# Flooding Bayesian rating creates values out of range

Tags: algorithm, bayesian, rating-system

I'm trying to apply the [Bayesian rating formula](http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating), but if I rate 1 out of 5 thousand of hundreds, the final rating is greater than 5.

For example, a given item has no votes and after voting 170,000 times with 1 star, its final rating is 5.23. If I rate 100, it has a normal value.

Here is what I have in PHP.

```
<?php
// these values came from DB
$total_votes     = 2936;    // total of votes for all items
$total_rating    = 582.955; // sum of all ratings
$total_items     = 202;

// now the specific item, it has no votes yet
$this_num_votes  = 0;
$this_score      = 0;
$this_rating     = 0;

// simulating a lot of votes with 1 star
for ($i=0; $i < 170000; $i++) { 
    $rating_sent = 1; // the new rating, always 1

    $total_votes++; // adding 1 to total
    $total_rating = $total_rating+$rating_sent; // adding 1 to total

    $avg_num_votes = ($total_votes/$total_items); // Average number of votes in all items
    $avg_rating = ($total_rating/$total_items);   // Average rating for all items
    $this_num_votes = $this_num_votes+1;          // Number of votes for this item
    $this_score = $this_score+$rating_sent;       // Sum of all votes for this item
    $this_rating = $this_score/$this_num_votes;   // Rating for this item

    $bayesian_rating = ( ($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes);
}
echo $bayesian_rating;
?>
```

Even if I flood with 1 or 2:

```
$rating_sent = rand(1,2)
```

The final rating after 100,000 votes is over 5.

I just did a new test using

```
$rating_sent = rand(1,5)
```

And after 100,000 I got a value completely out of range range (10.53). I know that in a normal situation no item will get 170,000 votes while all the other items get no vote. But I wonder if there is something wrong with my code or if this is an expected behavior of Bayesian formula considering the massive votes.

**Edit**

Just to make it clear, here is a better explanation for some variables.

```
$avg_num_votes   // SUM(votes given to all items)/COUNT(all items)
$avg_rating      // SUM(rating of all items)/COUNT(all items)
$this_num_votes  // COUNT(votes given for this item)
$this_score      // SUM(rating for this item)
$bayesian_rating // is the formula itself
```

The formula is: `( (avg_num_votes * avg_rating) + (this_num_votes * this_rating) ) / (avg_num_votes + this_num_votes)`. Taken from [here](http://www.thebroth.com/blog/118/bayesian-rating)

Comment: What are the values of the variables you use to calculate `$bayesian_rating`? `$avg_num_votes` and others.

Comment: I edited the question to add a better explanation for some variables. I start to think that when a item gets too many votes while other items don't get new votes, the rating of this item tends to infinite.

Comment: But what are the actual values? Can you print them?

Comment: rrenaud already found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to divide by total_votes rather than total_items when calculating avg_rating.

I made the changes and got something that behaves much better here.

http://codepad.org/gSdrUhZ2

Comment: Good lord... 2 hours looking at this and didn't see that. Just perfect! Thanks.