# Apply Bayesian average in a NON 5-star rating system

Tags: php, statistics, ranking, rating, bayesian

I am looking forward to apply the bayesian approach to prioritize a list that could take the number of likes, dislikes and review counts into consideration.

The approach listed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011241/flooding-bayesian-rating-creates-values-out-of-range) relies on the bayesian average:

`$bayesian_rating = ( ($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes);`

In my case, there are no `$avg_rating` since its not a 5-star system, it will never exist, the number of likes, dislikes and reviews always increments therefore i need to take care of the true representation of the listing.

The solution in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57849/5-star-ratings-bayesian-or-weighted-average) was not enough to decide on an approach.

What would the best solution be in case i want to apply a mathematical approach?

Edit added:
Ref. [@Ina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/825050/ina) , it is possible to reflect the 5-star system if i multiply the likes by 5 which makes it with the highest value in a 5-star system.

Getting back to the code, after adding some extra variables to take care of (likes, dislikes, number of reviews, number of times added to basket) , i am not sure the what can i fill the `$avg_rating` and `$this_rating` with?

Here is the code so far:

```
// these values extracted from the database
    $total_all_likes = 10; //total likes of all the products
    $total_all_dislikes = 5; //total dislikes of all the products
    $total_all_reviews = 7; //total reviews of all the products
    $total_all_addedToBasket = 2; //total of products that has been added to basket for all the users
    $total_all_votes = ($total_all_likes *5) + $total_all_dislikes;  //total of likes and dislikes
    $total_all_weight = $total_all_votes + $total_all_reviews + $total_all_addedToBasket; //total interactions on all the products
    $total_all_products = 200; //total products count

    //Get the average
    $avg_like = ($total_all_likes*5)/$total_all_votes; //Average of likes of all the votes 
    $avg_dislike = $total_all_dislikes/$total_all_votes; //Average of dislikes of all the votes 
    $avg_reviews = $total_all_reviews/$total_all_products; //Average of reviews of all the products
    $avg_addedToBasket = $total_all_addedToBasket/$total_all_products; //Average of added to basket count of all the products
    $avg_weight = $avg_like + $avg_dislike + $avg_reviews + $avg_addedToBasket; //Total average weight

    //New product, it has not been liked, disliked, added to basket or reviewed 
    $this_like = 0 *5;
    $this_dislike = 0;
    $this_votes  = $this_like + $this_dislike;
    $this_review     = 0;
    $this_addedToBasket = 0;
    $this_weight = $this_votes + $this_review + $this_addedToBasket;

    //$avg_rating
    //$this_rating

    $bayesian_rating = (($avg_weight * $avg_rating) + ($this_weight * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_weight + $this_weight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a 5-star system, you have a binary system. People either 'like' or 'dislike'. The ratings are therefore naturally a number between 0 and 1 calculated by:

```
likes / (likes + dislikes)
```

You do not need to multiply by 5 to imitate a 5* rating system.

Your code then becomes:

```
$avg_rating = $total_all_likes / ($total_all_likes + $total_all_dislikes)
$this_rating = $this_like / ($this_like + $this$total_num_positive_votes / $total_num_votes) // Check you're not dividing by 0
$bayesian_rating = (($avg_num_votes * $avg_rating) + ($this_num_votes * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_num_votes + $this_num_votes);
```

If you want to also take into account the number of 'baskets' and 'reviews' you can simply treat them as more 'weight'

```
$this_weight = $this_addedToBasket + $this_votes + $this_review;
$avg_votes = $total_all_votes / $total_all_products;
$avg_weight = $avg_addedToBasket + $avg_votews + $avg_reviews;
$bayesian_rating = (($avg_weight * $avg_rating) + ($this_weight * $this_rating) ) / ($avg_weight + $this_weight);
```

This will give you a good relative ranking, however if you wish to see meaningful scores between 0 and 1, then you can normalise by dividing away the weight added by baskets and reviews.

Comment: Do you mean `$total_num_positive_votes = total likes / (total likes + total dislikes)` ? And what about the other criteria's such as number of reviews? Where could that fit in the $bayesian_rating ?

Comment: No:
total_num_positive_votes is simply total likes.
total_num_votes is total likes + total dislikes


The Bayesian Rating doesn't take into account the number of reviews given. 

I'm not sure how it could be added, could you perhaps describe your problem in a bit more detail? As I understand it right now, you have a list of products, and each product has a number of votes (positive or negative) and a number of reviews (neutral).

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. In fact, this list of products can be added to basket, liked, dislike and reviewed. What i was searching for is an algorithm that will take into consideration **all** these counts of these variables and add them up into the `$bayesia_rating` to obtain a certain _weight_ that will help to sort the list in a 'meaningful' way as the Bayesian approach does in a 5 start system.

Comment: I have updated my question accordingly, i am not sure of the `$avg_rating` and `$this_rating` values and would the code that i have posted normalize the weight as you included in your answer? Appreciate the help.

Comment: I've clarified the variables leading up to the final answer for you.